# Parallel Data Flow Task in SSIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, dataflowtask

I am facing a problem for data flow task for parallel execution to insert rows into a single table e.g TABLE_DESTINATION from a source Table e.g TABLE_SOURCE.I do not directly insert the row into the table "TABLE_DESTINATION" . I use a stored procedure to insert the rows in as there are some Logic before insert.

There are almost 1 million records in my source table. I need to insert them into the destination table.

What I did? I created 4 data flow task(DFT). In Each DFT I mapped each table to the stored procedure. Create each OLEDB connection and kept the RetainConnection as True

Where the problem Is? When I started executing them, it goes into deadlock state.The DFT does not do anything. It stays in yellow color.

Comment: You need to copy data from table to another ?

Comment: yes. i need to insert data from one table to another but based on some condition which is mentioned in the stored procedure.i just need to call the procedure by mapping the input parameters from the source table.

Comment: The deadlock could simply be due to how the stored procedure is performing the insert. Post the definition.

Comment: Are both source and destination tables on the same server?   There is almost certainly a better way to do this than parallel data flows.

Comment: I have had issues with SSIS going to and from the same server.  Try making two connection objects and use one for the read and a different one for the write.

Comment: Yes, both are on same server.can you suggest a way out @ Tab . @Alan: i will give your answer a try.